# learning_rate is not a legal parameter

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to test my model by implementing GridSearchCV. But I cannot seem to add learning rate and momentum as parameters in GridSearch. Whenever I try to execute the code by adding those, I am getting an error.

Here is the model I've created:

```
def define_model(optimizers="SGD"):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers, metrics='accuracy')
    return model
```

GridSearch that I've implemented:

```
learn_rate=(0.0001,0.001)
momentum = (0.1, 0.5)
epochs = [5]
batches = [16]

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=define_model, verbose=2)
param_grid = dict(epochs = epochs, lr = learn_rate, momentum = momentum, batch_size = batches)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid= param_grid, n_jobs = 1, cv = 3)

grid_result = grid.fit(trainX, trainY)
print("Best: %f using %s" %(grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

And here is the error I've encountered:

```
~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py in check_params(self, params)
    104       else:
    105         if params_name != 'nb_epoch':
--> 106           raise ValueError('{} is not a legal parameter'.format(params_name))
    107 
    108   def get_params(self, **params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument

ValueError: lr is not a legal parameter
```

Comment: Check out the documentation for gridsearchcv

Comment: I just peeked at one of my old scripts.  Typically learning rate is `lr`, however for the GridSearchCV I have the dictionary key as `learning_rate` try changing `lr = learn_rate` to `learning_rate = learn_rate`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LPR Tried it, but it didn't work. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have optimizer in params. So, you don't need to put it as an argument in your function. Instead, you may need to mention the learning_rate and momentum as arguments in your function and add SGD directly where it should be:

```
def define_model(lr, momentum):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr, momentum), metrics='accuracy')

    return model
```